# VB6 Wrong Events fires on F5

Tags: events, vb6, activex-exe

I have a grid on a user control, which is on a user document vbd page, which is in ActiveX exe Application 
This is the event I get when pressing F5 on the grid

```
   Private Sub mnuRightClickRefresh_Click()
       'Call ...
   End Sub
```

When I press F3 on the grid 
I get the right event

```
   Private Sub grdObjects_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
       If KeyCode = 116 Then
        '...
       End If
   End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To be honest no I have no idea. The standard out of the box VB6 keyboard shortcuts are `F5 - Run>Start` and `F3 - Edit>Find Next`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to handle the _KeyUp function in two different functions. 
When you Press F5, make sure that no control has any focus (thus making the form it self as the focused control) then you may handle the event in the following way:

```
     Private Sub grdObjects_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
         Select Case KeyCode
              Case 116
                'Do Whatever F3 would want to do
              Case 118
                 'Do F5 Stuff
              Case 119
                  'Any other stuff for F6
          End Select
   End Sub
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted.